# How to create a share button in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, facebook

I was wondering if anyone knew a good way of creating an AS3 Facebook share button? I need to be able to customize the title, description and picture. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look: http://www.facebook.com/facebook-widgets/share.php

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<url>&t=<title>
```

In Flash:

```
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;

share_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shareClickHandler);

function shareClickHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    var varsShare:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    varsShare.u = 'http://domain.com/pageN.html';
    varsShare.t = 'Title Page';

    var urlFacebookShare:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php');
    urlFacebookShare.data = varsShare;
    urlFacebookShare.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

    navigateToURL(urlFacebookShare, '_blank');
}
```

In order to use a picture add the following Metatags:

```
<meta name="title" content="my title" />
<meta name="description" content="my description" />
<link rel="image_src" href="images/thumbnail_image.jpg" />
```

For more info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Comment: Hmm very interesting, I didnt think about it that way. Thanks for the tip, Ill check this out and let you know how it worked :)

Comment: How would you be able to share highscores with this method?

Answer (score 4):

here you go:

**redirect_uri** is required (and must redirect to your application site as defined in the facebook application settings page)

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
req.url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed";
var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
vars.app_id = "000000000000"; // your application's id
vars.link = "http://YourSite.com";
vars.picture = "https://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png";
vars.name = "name name";
vars.caption = "caption caption caption";
vars.description = "description description description";
vars.message = "message message message message message";
vars.redirect_uri = "http://YourSite.com";
req.data = vars;
req.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
navigateToURL(req, "_blank");
```

Comment: Docs: [one](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/) and [two](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you wish to share.

You can use the following url in a button:

`http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://www.mypage.com/`

which will pop up a page prompting the user to log in and share whatever they want to share.

Could you be more *precise* as to what you want to allow your users to share?

Comment: I just want the ability to share the location of the application, I know I can do it the way you explained above, but I wont be able to customize the title, description, etc...because AS3 can't pass off meta tags?