# youtube masthead - Add Facebook sharer

Tags: facebook, youtube

Is it possible to add a Facebook sharer button on a masthead youtube banner ? 
I can't find a way to do that without javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment i used this method : [How to create a share button in AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511918/how-to-create-a-share-button-in-as3)

It works, but it open a new page, i tried also this one to open a windowed page without use Javascript: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Facebook_share_button_in_AS3_without_external_Java-17581.html but i'm note sure that Youtube will be happy for this choice because Javascript is injected via AS3.