# Sharing url to Facebook from AS3 website

Tags: facebook, actionscript, sharing

I'm trying to share a URL from a flash as3 website, and i can't make it work quite properly...
I tried both ways given here : [How to create a share button in AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511918/how-to-create-a-share-button-in-as3)

First one works :

```
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;

share_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shareClickHandler);

function shareClickHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    var varsShare:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    varsShare.u = 'http://domain.com/pageN.html';
    varsShare.t = 'Title Page';

    var urlFacebookShare:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php');
    urlFacebookShare.data = varsShare;
    urlFacebookShare.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

    navigateToURL(urlFacebookShare, '_blank');
}
```

But, the post says :

```
In order to use a picture add the following Metatags:
<meta name="title" content="my title" />
<meta name="description" content="my description" />
<link rel="image_src" href="images/thumbnail_image.jpg" />
```

But HOW ????

The second solution shows how to add parameters:

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
req.url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed";
var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
vars.app_id = "000000000000"; // your application's id
vars.link = "http://YourSite.com";
vars.picture = "https://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png";
vars.name = "name name";
vars.caption = "caption caption caption";
vars.description = "description description description";
vars.message = "message message message message message";
vars.redirect_uri = "http://YourSite.com";
req.data = vars;
req.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
navigateToURL(req, "_blank");
```

But it's NOT using the Facebook sharer.....
I tried many many different ways to combine both solutions but i get nothing but weird url not working...

Please, can someone help me with that, or show me how to use that second solution but with the sharer ?

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 0):

You need to add OpenGraph Meta Tags to the Page you are trying to share (`http://domain.com/pageN.html` in your example above`). The metatags you've given in your question should be added there so the Facebook Sharing Script can pick it up.

Add the below code between the `<head>` and `</head>` tags in your HTML code:

```
<meta name="title" content="my title" />
<meta name="description" content="my description" />
<link rel="image_src" href="images/thumbnail_image.jpg" />
```

Comment: Ooooh ok alright, thank you ! The thing is those tags are generated dynamically in my as3 application with deeplink.... the corresponding html pages aren't actually existing...

Comment: That's the reason why it doesn't work then. Those pages need to exist, even if it's virtually.

Answer (score 0):

what I usually do - I create a facebook application - Website with Facebook Login, add Apps domains, then in your html add this javascript function:

```
function postToFacebook(link){              
                var caption = encodeURIComponent("this is cool");
                var name = encodeURIComponent("My cool Site");
                var pathToPicture = "http://yoursite.com/coolpicture.jpg";
                var redirect = "http://yoursite.com/redirect.html";
                var id = "123456789098876"; // your application id
                var theLink = link; // the link you want to share - this is passed as a variable from flash, similary you can pass any variables from  flash    

                var fbencoded = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=" + id + "&link=" + theLink + "&picture=" + pathToPicture + "&name=" + name +   "&caption=" + caption+ "&redirect_uri=" + redirect;
                window.open(fbencoded, "_blank");        
}
```

In flash whenever you want to share just call this javascript function and new window will be opened with facebook share window:

```
ExternalInterface.call("postToFacebook", "http://mysite.com/#/cool-page")
```

This way you can pass any vars to that function. For example you can have different pictures whenever someone is sharing, which would be impossible with just meta tags.....

Only thing is you have to create that redirect.html - which must be within your domain, that is linked to your application. In redirect you can have something simple as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.facebook.com">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

It would just redirect the user to facebook. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I got to use the Share Dialog from a button in AS3. I hope it helps you

```
import flash.net.navigateToURL;

share_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shareClickHandler);

function shareClickHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    var fb_title = "titulo";
    var fb_desc = "descripcion";
    var fb_url = "http://mibff.com.mx/";
    var fab_img = "http://mibff.com.mx/MiBFF_new.jpg";
    var facebookSharer:String = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=" + fb_title + "&p[summary]=" + fb_desc + "&p[url]=" + fb_url + "&p[images][0]=" + fab_img;
    var jscommand:String = "window.open('" + facebookSharer + "','win','width=626,height=316,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no');";
    var sharer:URLRequest = new URLRequest("javascript:" + jscommand + " void(0);");
    navigateToURL(sharer,"_self");

    //trace(facebookSharer);
}
```