# AIR Actionscript 3 Adding facebook share button

Tags: android, facebook, actionscript-3, mobile, air

basically, I'm currently building a mobile game using Actionscript 3.0 and AIR (Flash Pro 6). I want to add a facebook share button which the user can post their achievements to their wall.

The post will contains some words and an image.

I didn't know where to start. Can someone please help? thx b4...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511918/how-to-create-a-share-button-in-as3  this should do it
i think it should be the same api.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:
http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/

There is also documentation here:
http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/downloads/detail?name=GraphAPI_Documentation_1_8_1.zip&can=2&q=

Answer (score 0):

You can use this AS3 code to use FB share button.

```
fbShareBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent. CLICK, shareapp)
 function shareapp(evt:Event):void
            {

            var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
            req.url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed";
            var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
            vars.app_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"; // your application's id
            vars.link = "http://youromainhere";
            vars.picture = "http://yourimage";
            vars.name = "My Game";
            vars.caption = "My Score ";
            //vars.description = "My score is " + String(score) + " Try and you!";
            vars.redirect_uri = "http://yourdomainhere";
            req.data = vars;
            req.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
            navigateToURL(req, "_blank");

            }
```